# While loop still continues

Tags: python

When the user inputs anything but a number for the first input, the program should quit. But instead it just keeps going.

I tried to put many if ... break statements in the main function after the "a" to break it, but nothing helped.

```
def is_number(str):
    try:
        float(str)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
       

def is_valid_operator(operator):
    operators = ('+', '-', '*', '/')
    return operator in operators



def ask_for_a_number(force_valid_input):
    while force_valid_input is True:
        a = input('Please provide a number: ')
        if is_number(a):
            return float(a)
        else:
            if not force_valid_input:
                return None
            print("This doesn't look like a number, try again!")

def ask_for_an_operator(force_valid_input):
    while force_valid_input is True:
        operator = input('Please provide an operator: ')
        if is_valid_operator(operator):
            return operator
        else:
            if not force_valid_input:
                return None
            print('Unknown Operator')



def calc(operator, a, b):
    if not is_number(a) or not is_valid_operator(operator) or not is_number(b):
        return None
    result = 0
    if operator == '+':
        result = a + b
    elif operator == '-':
        result = a - b
    elif operator == '*':
        result = a * b
    elif operator == '/':
        if b != 0:
            result = a / b
        else:
            print('Error: Divide by zero is not allowed')
            return None

    return result

def main():
    while True:
        a = ask_for_a_number(force_valid_input = True)
        operator = ask_for_an_operator(force_valid_input = True)
        b = ask_for_a_number(force_valid_input = True)
        result = calc(operator, a, b)
        if result is not None:
            print(f'The result is {result}')
    
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What keeps going exactly? what inputs are you giving? what output do yo uget?

Comment: The `while True:` without a `break` in it is an infinite loop.

Comment: If I run the program it goes okay when I put every correct input. first number, operator, second number, and the result is there. but i would like to implement something that if the user inputs anything else instead of a number for the first input, the sequence should break and the program quits. I tried to do a "if a is None - break" statement in the while loop (and some variants of it) for the main function to break it , but it still keeps going.

Comment: You should have only one while loop in here. Keep the one in the main() and remove every other loops. Having nested loops is a bad practice and a code smell

Comment: I removed every while loop instead the main one and added the if not a return statement and  now it works, thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check whether `a` is a number or not, but then don't do anything if it isn't one. So check the value of a

```
a = ask_for_a_number(force_valid_input = True)
if not a:
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are using a while loop with True but never order it to stop. You'd need a `break` somewhere in there.
On another note, you don't need to check if a boolean `is True`, you can just do `if bool` or `while bool` as it returns True or False anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can just add a condition like below in main function

```
 a = ask_for_a_number(force_valid_input = True)
 if a == 'break': 
  break
```

And in the function ask_for_a_number return the 'break' string like below

```
 print("This doesn't look like a number, try again!");
 return 'break'
```